# A popup cursor-following tooltip with a fixed position doesn't let me to fill in an input element and jumps when far down a table (JSFIDDLE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make use of [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791568/4759176) tooltip code, but I've encountered a few problems. The tooltip doesn't let me type text in a `<input>` element and also makes jumps when I scroll far down the table, like this:

[image]

while it's supposed to follow the cursor. I made this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nuvgef12/ and here's the code:

**css**:

```
.tooltip {
display: inline-block;
position: fixed;
padding: .5em 1em;
background-color: red;
}
```

**html**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id="log">pageX: -, pageY: -</h4>
<div class="tooltip">I'm a tooltip!</div>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter something">
<table class='items'>
            <thead>
            <tr class="table-header">
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Icon</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            ...
```

**js**:

```
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
  $( ".tooltip" ).css({
    "left" : event.pageX,
    "top" : event.pageY
  });
});
```

**EDIT**:

The given solutions help with letting putting the text inside input, but there still exists the problem with jumping. It happens after a scroll down the table - the tooltip briefly disappears and then reappears much off to down and to the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add 1** to the **X** and **Y** **position** to allow you to select behind it, or add a `margin-top:1px` to your **.tooltip** will also work.

An easy fix to the scroll issue is to use `clientX` and `clientY` instead.

Here is the modified script:

```
$(window).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).text( "clientX: " + event.clientX + ", clientY: " + event.clientY );
  $( ".tooltip" ).css({
    "left" : event.clientX + 1,
    "top" : event.clientY + 1
  });  
});
```

[Here is the working code.](https://jsfiddle.net/52bv4tgp/)

You can read more **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y)** on the difference between them, but basically **pageX** is relative to the document's position **within** the viewport, which **changes when scrolled**, and **clientX** is relative to the viewport itself, which does not change in this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a little margin to your tooltip it will let your pointer click on the input instead of the tooltip

```css
.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working. However there jumping problem persists...

Comment: couldn't reproduce the jumping

Comment: Scroll once so that the cursur around middle-end of the table. The tooltip would jump.